# MSSQL - FOR DELETE trigger not working with inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can someone explain why this works -

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[T_tskmst_D]
   ON  [dbo].[tskmst]
   FOR DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for trigger here
        insert into [database].[dbo].[tskmst] (
            tskmst_revtm, tskmst_revtype, tskmst_id, tskmst_name, tskmst_desc,
            tskmst_type, owner_id, tskmst_public, tskmst_lstchgtm,
            nodmst_id, servicemst_id)
        select GETDATE(), 'D', d.tskmst_id, d.tskmst_name, d.tskmst_desc,
            d.tskmst_type, d.owner_id, d.tskmst_public, d.tskmst_lstchgtm,
            d.nodmst_id, d.servicemst_id
        from deleted d
END
```

But this doesn't -

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[T_tskmst_D]
   ON  [dbo].[tskmst]
   FOR DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for trigger here
        insert into [database].[dbo].[tskmst] (
            tskmst_revtm, tskmst_revtype, tskmst_id, tskmst_name, tskmst_desc,
            tskmst_type, owner_id, tskmst_public, tskmst_lstchgtm,
            nodmst_id, servicemst_id)
        select GETDATE(), 'D', d.tskmst_id, d.tskmst_name, d.tskmst_desc,
            d.tskmst_type, d.owner_id, d.tskmst_public, d.tskmst_lstchgtm,
            d.nodmst_id, d.servicemst_id
        from deleted d
                inner join tskmst tm on tm.tskmst_id = d.tskmst_id
END
```

I'm confused as to why an inner join on delete would stop the query from being able to copy the info?  Is it because the data is deleted before the inner join can happen?  Is it possible to copy the data BEFORE the delete occurs?

I can do from deleted but the problem is some tables contain text columns (don't ask) so I can't insert from deleted else I'm missing certain columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because if it FOR delete trigger.
It means that deleted row already doesn't exist in the table.

When you join something with nothing you always get nothing.

Comment: Thnx that's what I thought.  Begs the question then, is there any way to copy a text column from something in deleted?  As it stands if I do the insert into from deleted I have to exclude the text columns.

Comment: I didn't understand why you have to exclude text columns.

Comment: because if you try to do an insert into using text columns from inserted or deleted it fails.  ntext is not a valid column that can be used.

Comment: I see now. You should change the datatype of your `ntext` column to `nvarchar(max)`. `Ntext` data type will be deprecated soon: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx